# A riveting mystery: Android, Bitmaps (JPEGs), and the GridView of DEATH?

Tags: android

My app is exhibiting some very strange behavior. I have tried everything to resolve the issues I'm having, but, at this point, I'm at a total loss.

Some background information is in order (some details of the implementation that I'm providing might be overkill, but I want to make sure no stone is left unturned):

1. The app makes use of the device's camera, utilizing a SurfaceView with the necessary SurfaceHolder callbacks to open the device's Camera and take photos. That all works just fine.
2. The photos are then saved to the devices internal storage, using a FileOutPutStream. I then maintain a reference to the file path of each photo inside a plain old Java object, which is actually serialized and also written to the device's internal storage using an ObjectOutputStream.
3. The photos, which are in JPEG format, are later retrieved by grabbing the serialized ArrayList of my objects, grabbing the file path from those objects and passing it to my caching mechanism like so Bitmap bm = ImageCache.getSharedInstance().getBitmap(photoObject.filePath,getResources()); to return a Bitmap which I can use with an ImageView, whatever. I use this to for displaying the JPEGs in ListViews, GridViews, etc.

**Here's the problem:**

I have a View, which I've created programmatically, that has a sort of navigation bar at the top of it. All the navigation bar does is set the "main" part of my custom View class to display whatever other view I pass to it. So, my View class has a method like: setContent(View v) which simply removes all Views from the main part (or the area that I've carved out as the content area) and then adds the View you passed in to this content area.

So, if you click on nav button, it shows the photos along with some other data in a ListView, click another and it shows a GridView using the same photos. Right here is the problem. I like to call it THE GRIDVIEW OF DEATH. The GridView implementation is pretty straightforward and seems to work just fine when it's loaded.

```
mGalleryAdapter = new GalleryAdapter(MyActivity.this, list);
                        gridView.setAdapter(mGalleryAdapter);
```

Fine... but here's the issue. **Once the GridView is loaded and displays the data from the adapter, if you try to start any other activity or navigate to any other are of the app, the activities in question seem to launch, but the Views inside of them never display.** It is the strangest behavior. If you start with the ListView displaying and then navigate to some other tab (yea, I'm using tabs to sort of mimick iPhone style UITabs), everything is fine. The activity loads, the views display... everything is fine. But once you click to display the GridView, the app just seems to melt. Aaaaand, here's the catch. Whatever activity you've navigate to after displaying the GridView, will first display an empty, white activity (with no view). But if, for example, you long-press the home button and switch to some other running app and then come back to my app, the newly launched activities then display the views inside of them just fine and the app resumes normally. Strange indeed.

I must mention that I originally had the app crash several times because of "exceeding the VM budget." This was clearly related to issues with the JPEGs and their memory usage. From the stuff I've read online, the main fix to this is to crank up the BitmapFactory.Options sampleSize. Well, that's exactly what I've done. I've cranked it way up to reduce the image size:

```
public Bitmap getBitmap(String filepath, Resources resources){
        SoftReference<Bitmap> reference;
        if(resourcesLoaded.containsKey(filepath)){
            reference = resourcesLoaded.get(filepath);
            if(reference.get() == null){
                int width = resources.getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
                int height = (int) (42*((float)(((float)width)/320.0)));
                BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                opts.inSampleSize = 28;
                opts.outHeight = height;
                opts.inTempStorage = new byte[16*1024];

                opts.outWidth = width;
                opts.inPurgeable = true;
                Bitmap bit = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath ,opts);
                reference = new SoftReference<Bitmap>(bit);
                resourcesLoaded.put(filepath, reference);
            }
        }else{
            int width = resources.getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
            int height = (int) (42*((float)(((float)width)/320.0)));
            BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            opts.outHeight = height;
            opts.outWidth = width;
            opts.inTempStorage = new byte[16*1024];

            opts.inSampleSize = 28;
            opts.inPurgeable = true;
            Bitmap bit = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath ,opts);
            reference = new SoftReference<Bitmap>(bit);
            resourcesLoaded.put(filepath, reference);
        }
        return reference.get();
    }
```

And, that's the weird thing, the app doesn't even crash now. Using caching and reducing the image size seems to have eliminated that crash (at least on some of the devices I've tested on), but this strange behavior, WHICH ONLY OCCURS ONCE LOADING THE GRIDVIEW OF DEATH and then navigating away from it, persists.

On a related note, I have used some third party app on my phone to see the current memory usage of my app and, at times, it creeps up to 100MB! Every time I take a photo with the app and save it to the internal storage, the memory usage seems to jump considerably (generally starts around 30-40MB and climbs from there). So clearly, there are memory issues going on. But again, the app won't crash with a "exceeded VM budget" error. On the other hand, it's hard to ignore the obvious memory issues with the app.

I fully realize that some of my implementation is not perfect, not super memory efficient, and that using singletons to hold the ArrayList of my objects, etc might not be the greatest way to go. But even still, this behavior seems inexplicable.

**To summarize: the app will load completely blank activities ONCE AND ONLY ONCE you've clicked to display the images (that are stored as JPEGs on the device) in the GridView. If you never click to use the GridView, everything is fine.**

What's with the Gridview of death?

(I'm happy to provide the code for any portions you think are relevant.)

UPDATE:

**Thanks @CommonsWare for all your patience and advice.** Really appreciate it and it's always nice to have the unofficial Android developer advocate on the case. Turns out that using Fragments did, in fact, solve all of my problems. For a moment, I thought I had fully implemented the Fragment solution, but quickly realized that I was still "setting the content" of some base View that was loaded in my Fragment to my GridView. By creating a new framgent containing the Grid View and loading it, all problems seem to be solved and the app is now stable!

UPDATE: Well, I spoke too soon :( Apparently this GridView is still causing problems. Now when I switch to a new tab, I can see that the button I'm using for the tab was clicked, but when it calsl `setCurrentTab()` nothing happens. App remains frozen in the GridView screen.

Comment: That's a long question! Can you please put the relevant code and facts in a more concise manner?

Comment: @Vikram, would love to if you could ask for specifics ;)

Comment: (note) I think that this question is way too long to most of and due to that you wont be getting much/relative answers.

Comment: I am very confident that you are not hitting 100MB of heap usage, as you don't have that much room. Even the "starts around 30-40MB" is impossible on the vast majority of devices. In terms of your root problem, if you're trying to use `ActivityGroup`, and the activities you are launching are really being launched into this group, I can see this sort of behavior possibly occurring. Since `ActivityGroup` is now deprecated, if this is your scenario, I suggest finding a way to move away from `ActivityGroup`, perhaps switching to fragments.

Comment: @Commonsware, indeed. I am using ActivityGroup. ;) Why is this behavior understandable to you if I'm using ActivityGroup?

Comment: @LuxuryMode: Because `ActivityGroup` was quite the hack, one of the reasons it is now deprecated. What an `ActivityGroup` basically does is rip the `Views` out of one activity and put them in another activity's designated container. Hence, the inner activity is going to be affected by any issues that peers, or the outer activity, have going on. It's not like the members of the `ActivityGroup` get a totally clean slate like a regular standalone activity would.

Comment: @CommonsWare, gotcha. Looks like I'm gonna have to gut the project and start boning up on the Fragments API. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @CommonsWare, so to replace my current implementation (which is using ActivityGroup) with a solution that relies on Fragments, will I just have each "grouping of activities" actually be fragments, and simply load a new fragment on some event (fragments which in my case, will always fill the screen and appear like a normal activity)? And then when switching tabs have some super FragmentManager that clears the stack (?) and then loads the appropriate fragment?

Comment: @LuxuryMode: "and simply load a new fragment on some event" -- that's typical. That's how Honeycomb tabs work, and you can get the same action bar and API for pre-Honeycomb devices via ActionBarSherlock. "some super FragmentManager" -- that's probably the activity hosting the fragments. "that clears the stack" -- the fragments probably are not on the BACK stack.

Comment: @CommonsWare. Thanks as always. I'm trying to make sure that the external behavior of this implementation is the same as the TabActivity + ActivityGroup implementation that I've been using. I'm assuming there's a way to override the back button behavior so you can go back to some previously "displayed" fragment? Just making sure I'm thinking about this right. I'm really gonna be using Fragments in place of activities....loading fragments instead of starting activities. I'm babbling... my question is: I'll be able to handle some sort of stack where I can go back and forth between fragments?

Comment: @LuxuryMode: "a way to override the back button behavior": yes, but it's opt-in when you create the `FragmentTransaction`. "I'll be able to handle some sort of stack where I can go back and forth between fragments?" -- since this is a tabbed UI, I assumed that pressing a tab would move you between fragments, given what you wrote. Again, this is fairly natural with the new tab API available in the action bar, native in Honeycomb and backwards-compatible via ActionBarSherlock.

Comment: @CommonsWare. Gotcha. Thanks again. Anything wrong with continuing to use TabActivity which simply launches my super fragmentsactivity with an intent extra to determine which fragment to load in onCreate?

Comment: @LuxuryMode: "Anything wrong with continuing to use TabActivity" -- `TabActivity` is deprecated and is designed to work with a `TabHost` and `TabWidget`. I have no idea how well those will play with fragments, as I have not tried it. "which simply launches my super fragmentsactivity with an intent extra to determine which fragment to load in onCreate" -- huh? Methinks you have too many activities here.

Comment: @CommonsWare, actually I just realized I'm thinking about it wrong. My master activity should just take care of starting my fragmentactivities. calling startActivity should be fine. The only thing changing here is that my fragmentactivities will now take care of embedded activities through the fragments api, instead of through activitygroup. Make sense?

Comment: @CommonsWare. I wasn't being clear. There actually aren't that many activities. Honestly, I'm doing all of this because it's high time (as the issues I'm having demonstrate) to move away from deprecated APIs ;) Also, I guess I don't need TabActivity at all. I'll simply create a layout that looks like tabs and just have each one, onClick, start its appropriate fragmentsactivity

Comment: @CommonsWare, well bad news. I switched everything over to Fragments. I used the code sample available @ http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html which shows how to use Fragments with a TabHost. I've still got the same issue. When I switch to another tab, which performs the trick referenced in the link to show the tab content. When I try switching to another tab after displaying my GridView, the tab is blank. If I never click to display the GridView then everything works just fine.